# Cannot make GWT devmode plugin work with Firefox

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I always get this error below when running GWT devmode on Firefox (version 21) with this [GWT Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/detail?name=gwt-dev-plugin-1-21-rc.xpi).

**Error:**

```
[INFO] WARN [EnvUtil] enable reachability analysis with -Derrai.compile.perf.perform_reachability_analysis=true
[INFO] INFO [IOCBootstrapGenerator] generated IOC bootstrapping class in 6499ms (5174 beans processed)
[INFO] INFO [IOCBootstrapGenerator] using IOC bootstrapping code at: D:\magick\app.ui\.errai\BootstrapperImpl.java
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Bootstrapper' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Container.bootstrapContainer(Container.java:55)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Container.onModuleLoad(Container.java:34)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[ERROR] Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:503)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
[ERROR]     ... 12 more
```

However, I don't get this error in the same GWT application when using Google Chrome.

What could be the problem? What am I missing? I am using GWT maven plugin:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer in two parts:

1st: The plugin you are using currently is in RC status. I recommend using an older version of FF (I use 18 with [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/detail?name=gwt-dev-plugin-1-18.xpi&can=2&q=)) with the appropriate plugin for developing purpose. Its a hard job for the plugin-team to keep up to the FF release cycle, which is short as you know.

2nd: Check your gwt.xml. There might be a missing inherit. One of the following:

```
<inherits name="org.jboss.errai.common.ErraiCommon" />
<inherits name="org.jboss.errai.bus.ErraiBus" />
<inherits name="org.jboss.errai.enterprise.CDI" />
<inherits name="org.jboss.errai.ioc.Container" />
<inherits name="org.jboss.errai.marshalling.ErraiMarshalling" />
<inherits name="org.jboss.errai.databinding.DataBinding" />
<inherits name="org.jboss.errai.enterprise.Jaxrs" />
```

Comment: I already reverted back to FF 8.0.1 with GWT plugin version 1.21 and still get the error. However the same app, and the same dev mode instance work with Chrome, when instead of pasting the generated GWT URL to FF to Chrome and it works!